# ¿Cómo funciona esta función relacionada a colas en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy estudiando javascript y me aparece el siguiente ejercicio denominado como; "**Permanece en línea**" y dice lo siguiente:

"*En Informática una cola (queue) es una estructura de datos abstracta donde los elementos se mantienen en orden. Los nuevos elementos se pueden añadir en la parte posterior de la cola y los elementos antiguos se retiran de la parte delantera de la cola.*"

Esto lo entiendo perfectamente y me aparece el siguiente ejercicio:

> 1. Escribe una función nextInLine que tome un arreglo (arr) y un número (item) como argumentos.
> 2. Agrega el número al final del arreglo, luego elimina el primer elemento del arreglo.
> 3. La función nextInLine debe entonces devolver el elemento que fue removido.
>    Donde los objetivos son los siguientes:
> 4. nextInLine([], 5) debe devolver un número.
> 5. nextInLine([], 1) debe devolver 1
> 6. nextInLine([2], 1) debe devolver 2
> 7. nextInLine([5,6,7,8,9], 1) debe devolver 5
> 8. Después de nextInLine(testArr, 10), testArr[4] debe ser igual a 10

El código que me aparece es:

```js
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  // Cambia solo el código debajo de esta línea

  return item;
  // Cambia solo el código encima de esta línea
}

// Configuración
let testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Muestra el código
console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 6));
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
```

La cuestión es que soy capaz de solucionarlo pero no entenderlo a la perfección, sé que push es capaz de agregar nuevos elementos que pasé como parámetros al final de un arreglo y luego devuelve la longitud.

También sé que shift quita elimina el primer elemento de un arreglo cambiando la longitud del mismo y, que el valor de retorno que obtenemos del método shift es el elemento eliminado.

Por ende la solución es esta:

```js
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  // Cambia solo el código debajo de esta línea
  arr.push(item);
  var quesito = arr.shift();
  return quesito;
  // Cambia solo el código encima de esta línea
}

// Configuración
let testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Muestra el código
console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 6));
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
```

La cosa no es la solución, sino que requiero ayuda para comprender en su totalidad el funcionamiento. Ya que ahorita, sé cómo solucionarlo por lo mismo que estoy muy metido en esto de javascript, pero si tuviera una situación donde viera este tipo de problema, siento que se me va a olvidar.

Comment: Yo creo que tu propia explicación de las funciones que usas y como las usas demuestra que ya lo has entendido.

Comment: Lo único "complejo" es el objetivo 5, donde debes entender que testArr es cualquier array con 5 elementos, para que al meter el 10 y sacar el primero, el 10 quede en la posición 4 del indice (los índices empiezan por 0 como el primer elemento)

Comment: Creo que no me se explicar muy bien, lo que no entiendo es el paso a paso que es lo que comprende la computadora o como lo traduce, o sea, ahorita lo entiendo, pero no del todo, se como llegar a la solución pero no comprenderlo, es como saber que 2 + 2 es 4 en automático, pero no que significa bien cada elemento de la suma. Es complicado de explicar lo que me falta entender, pero en pocas palabras requiero averiguar el paso a paso

Comment: no entiendo el todo tu pregunta, pero por lo que dices shift efectivamente remueve el primer elemento de un arreglo pero es un metodo mutable por lo que al ejecutarlo cambia el arreglo en si, por lo que no es necesario asignarlo a una variable.

Comment: Las Pilas, Colas y Listas, son elementos que trascienden la programación (se utilizan en varias otras disciplinas). Un Array en javascript tiene la peculiaridad que se comporta como las 3 a la vez (en otro lenguajes no pasa eso)

Comment: @Bryro El retorno del shift no es el array, es el elemento eliminado

Comment: Corso sabes punteros y listas enlazadas ???

Comment: @Yussef tengo noción por C++ no lo domino definitivamente, pero intente estudiarlo en su momento pero es más complejo que javascript, así que voy paso a paso, ¿en javascript hay punteros o a que se le denomina puntero en javascript?

Comment: Es que la respuesta del ¿por qué y cómo? saca el primero y mete el último, va intrínsicamente ligado a esos conceptos. Javascript es un mal lenguaje para tratar de entender que pasa por detrás, porque como te decía el array de javascript es array, lista, pila y cola al mismo tiempo. Pero el asunto va por la asignación de memoria a cada elemento, luego uno o varios punteros a esos espacios en memoria. Como elimina  un elemento?? depende de la implementación. Generalmente para el último elemento no hay mucho problema, se elimina el espacio y el puntero se deja apuntando a nulo.

Comment: Cont: Para los otros elementos puede haber más problema, porque hay que reordenar los punteros. Ahora existen otro concepto que es el Garbadge collector. Donde en lenguajes que lo aplican, la recolección de memoria la hace automáticamente. En ese caso solo dejas los puntero apuntando a null.  Me fui por la tangente, es que el tema es demasiado complejo para explicar si no se conocen conceptos previos (igual que explicar porque 1+1 =2)

Comment: Te entendí perfectamente, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

A continuación lo explico paso a paso lo que quería averiguar, para esto vamos por partes a lo que se refiere el ejercicio, cito:

***1. Escribe una función nextInLine que tome un arreglo (arr) y un número (item) como argumentos.***

Solo haciendo caso a esto, el código quedaría así:

```js
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
}
```

Solo hice una función nombrándola `nextInLine`, con *arr* (primer argumento) e *item* (segundo argumento).

Posterior a ello se me pide lo siguiente:

***2. Agrega el número al final del arreglo, luego elimina el primer elemento del arreglo.***

Para esto, partí en dos la instrucción, por ende, primero la parte donde dice: "***Agrega el número al final del arreglo***". Para esto use el método "push", que como lo tengo entendido: "***push es capaz de agregar nuevos elementos que pase como parámetros al final de un arreglo y luego devuelve la longitud.***", por ende el código continuaría con:

```js
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
    arr.push(item);
}
```

Donde:

- **arr** es el arreglo
- **push()** es el método que usaré para agregar el elemento
- **item** es el "número" que se me pide que agregue al arreglo, o sea a **"arr"**

Cabe mencionar que *item* no tiene un valor, solo es un argumento de la función, como tal no es un número, por ende, solo se está estableciendo como si fuera una "fórmula", pero a esto se le denomina "función".

A partir de aquí, lo entendí todo y tiene mas sentido para mí que "***una cola (queue) es una estructura de datos abstracta***", ya que "aísla" una propiedad "ignorando" otras; no sé si me expliqué bien en esta parte, pero trato de ser lo más conciso.

Continuamos con la siguiente parte de la instrucción que dice: "***luego elimina el primer elemento del arreglo***":

```js
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
    arr.push(item);
    let comoNoLoVoyAEntenderALaBurger = arr.shift();
}
```

Donde:

- **let** es para definir/declarar una variable
- **comoNoLoVoyAEntenderALaBurger** es el nombre de la variable
- **=** es para establecer un valor a la variable
- **arr** es el arreglo al que se le eliminará el primer arreglo
- **shift()** es el método para eliminar el primer elemento
- **()** en los paréntesis no es necesario un valor, ya que si no se establece nada, **shift()** comprende en automático que eliminará el primer elemento del argumento que es "**arr**"

Finalmente pasamos a la última parte que dice "***La función nextInLine debe entonces devolver el elemento que fue removido.***", por ende, se debe usar la sentencia return, simplemente se cambia el valor return por el nombre de la variable, finalmente obteniendo el código:

```js
    function nextInLine(arr, item) {
      arr.push(item);
      var comoNoLoVoyAEntenderALaBurger = arr.shift();
      return comoNoLoVoyAEntenderALaBurger;
    }
```

Donde: "**return comoNoLoVoyAEntenderALaBurger;**", finalizará la ejecución de la función y especifica un valor para ser devuelto a quien llama a la función.

Finalmente para validar esta información, acorde con los objetivos que requiere el ejercicio, que son los siguientes:

1. nextInLine([], 5) debe devolver un número.
2. nextInLine([], 1) debe devolver 1
3. nextInLine([2], 1) debe devolver 2
4. nextInLine([5,6,7,8,9], 1) debe devolver 5
5. Después de nextInLine(testArr, 10), testArr[4] debe ser igual a 10

Simplemente muestro el mensaje en la consola web, agregando la variable del ejercicio "***testArr***", por ende el código quedaría:

```js
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  arr.push(item);
  var comoNoLoVoyAEntenderALaBurger = arr.shift();
  return comoNoLoVoyAEntenderALaBurger;
}

let testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(nextInLine([], 5));
console.log(nextInLine([], 1));
console.log(nextInLine([2], 1));
console.log(nextInLine([5,6,7,8,9], 1));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 10));
console.log(testArr[4]);
```

Algo muy interesante del ejercicio es que viene el siguiente código;

```js
console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 6));
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
```

Que va con la intención de ayudar al estudiante a comprender mejor el tema, solo es cosa de encontrarle un poco de lógica. Todo el código junto quedaría:

```js
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  // Cambia solo el código debajo de esta línea
  arr.push(item);
  var comoNoLoVoyAEntenderALaBurger = arr.shift();
  return comoNoLoVoyAEntenderALaBurger;
  // Cambia solo el código encima de esta línea
}

// Configuración
let testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Muestra el código
console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 6));
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));

console.log(nextInLine([], 5));
console.log(nextInLine([], 1));
console.log(nextInLine([2], 1));
console.log(nextInLine([5,6,7,8,9], 1));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 10));
console.log(testArr[4]);
```

Comment: Buena explicación. Me quedó claro que no me había quedado clara tu pregunta

Comment: Te recomiendo que mires la estructura de datos en Árbol y su recorridos en profundidad. Te va a encantar!

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos, estoy muy feliz y claro que si le voy a dar un estudio a la estructura de datos en árbol, me parece que eso me va a ayudar mucho a javascript orientado a objetos, es fantástico lo que se puede hacer con esto, muchas gracias :D

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.